# jQuery .click() does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Let's say that I got code like that:

```
<div class="div">
  <input type="submit" value="Button" class="button1">
</div>
```

And then when I put in the console this code:

```
document.getElemetsByClassName('button1')[0].click();
```

It does click the button, but when I try the same thing in jQuery with arrays:

```
array = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
$(array[0]).find('button1').click();
```

It does not work and does not return any error messages so I don't know what is wrong. Thanks from above for help.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to have a CSS class called "div": are all divs "div", or just some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you are using is a tag selector. Change it to class selector:

```
$(array[0]).find('.button1').click();
//----------------^ Add a . here.
```

I would also better change this to:

```
$(".div .button1").trigger("click");
```

Works better this way, using [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: What is the difference between trigger and click? I have read some informations that were saying that click is shortened trigger.

Comment: @Lotherad I am not sure. But most of the time, `.trigger("click")` works better than `.click()` as jQuery generates an event object to trigger it.

Comment: @Lotherad Or if by any chance, is your HTML is dynamically generated?

Comment: I think I'm dumb or something but it does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/btbp0zLk/1/

Comment: @Lotherad You aren't including jQuery in your fiddle. Updated -> https://jsfiddle.net/o9snaf42/

Comment: @Lotherad You get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in console, because you haven't added jQuery. I have added it for you and it works. This is really dumb! `:P` Check out: [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/smfkqh2f/)

Comment: If there is `<div class="example example2">` then I have to use find('.example2') right? I don't have to write find('.example example2')?

Comment: @Lotherad It would be either `find('.example2')` **or** `find('.example.example2')` and not spaces inbetween.

Comment: It still does not work in my code. I got div that contains many elements but only one with class name that I'm trying to find and it still does not work.

`$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(wszyscy[0]).find('.clearfix.adminActions').trigger("click");
 });`

Comment: @Lotherad try the second type. This one: `$(".div .button1").trigger("click");`

Comment: But I have to use this array, it can't be `$(wszyscy[0] .adminActions)` the div that contains this class that I wan't to click is in the array.

Comment: @Lotherad The above code should work. Kindly tell what's there in: `wszyscy`?

Comment: `var wszyscy = document.getElementsByClassName('_4-u2 _4-u8');` it contains divs, each div has the class that I want to click so thats why I'm using `wszyscy[0]`.

Comment: There you go but I'm working on facebook page so I can't really get the HTML for you. http://jsbin.com/jibutoyoca/edit?html,css,js

Comment: @Lotherad I don't understand how can someone help you without the necessary HTML. I am just rebuilding something for you.

Comment: It is really hard to give yout his HTML but I'm working on facebook page, this one where all users of group are shown and you got this gear icon. http://s29.postimg.org/g2aqpu6s7/screenshot_1661.png And every user row class is "_4-u2 _4-u8" and each row contains gear icon div with class "clearfix adminActions".

Comment: @Lotherad Did you try the above JSBin?

Comment: Your code `$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.clearfix.adminActions').click(function () {
    alert("You just clicked 'This is clearfix.' div!");
  });` won't work because there is more than 1 clearfix adminactions div

Comment: Oh man, it just started working! I did put `$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(wszyscy[0]).find('.img.sp_yMRT5OUDJGX.sx_a45b7f').trigger("click");
 });` with all those dots it started to work, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`button1` is `class`. You should add a dot(.) before `button1` to select `button1` `class` like following.

```
$(array[0]).find('.button1').click();
```